# program to convert .sln file into mingw command

Tags: c++

I'm going to be building a simple application with VS2012 (only 1 projet), and I want to know if there is any easy way to also compile it with gcc or mingw for windows.

I was thinking to make a program that would parse the .vcproj file, look for the .cpp files simply then compile the same file with mingw for instance.
But is there also something like that that exists?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but you could do the inverse and have visual studio build using makefiles.

Comment: @zero298 : the thing is, I find it way more easier to manage the solution files from Visual Studio

Comment: See here for a SLN --> makefile converter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870533/where-can-i-find-a-tool-to-convert-a-vs-solution-to-a-gcc-makefile

Comment: Still looking for a good tool like this myself... I did come across cmakeconverter (https://github.com/pavelliavonau/cmakeconverter) to build `*.sln` files but it hardly ever works :-(